# Banking application classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I have this banking app with this structure
[image]

I've created all the classes (BankAccount, SavingAccount , CurrentAccount) 
I'm having a problem with Bank class I don't Know why the functions in Bank class are not executing.

This is my code (I didn't include all the functions):

```
class Bank  {
    constructor(){
        this.accounts = [];
    }
    addAccount(acc) {
        this.accounts.push(acc) 
    }
    displayAllVAccounts(){
        this.accounts.forEach(acc => console.log(acc));
    }
}
module.exports = Bank;
```

App class:

```
let BankAccount = require('./model/BankAccount');
let SavingAccount = require('./model/SavingAccount');
let CurrentAccount = require('./model/CurrentAccount');
let Bank = require('./model/Bank');


let saveAcc1 = new SavingAccount( 123 , 500 , 1000);
Bank.addAccount(saveAcc1);


let currAcc1 = new CurrentAccount ( 234 , 4000 ,15 );
Bank.addAccount(currAcc1);


let currAcc2 = new CurrentAccount ( 345 , 35000 , 25);
Bank.addAccount(currAcc2);


let saveAcc2 = new SavingAccount( 456 , 60000 , 1000);
Bank.addAccount(saveAcc2);
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of Bank `let bank = new Bank;` and then use `bank.addAccount` instead of `Bank.addAccount`

Comment: Also note that using JavaScript's number type for important financial values is not best practice, they're too imprecise. (`0.1 + 0.2` is notoriously `0.30000000000000004` -- and **no**, you can't just round to two places to deal with it.)

Comment: @Paulpro or do `module.exports = new Bank;`

Comment: @Paulpro thinks it worked :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a loot at following code;

```
let Bank = require('./model/Bank');

let saveAcc1 = new SavingAccount( 123 , 500 , 1000);
new Bank().addAccount(saveAcc1);
```